# I'm about to get a raise. Should i refuse it if I'm now thinking to resign?

Tags: work-environment, resignation, raise

I'm a software engineer and in this time of the year at my company we are getting raises based on our performance. I already told my boss how much I want and he agreed, telling me that he now has to see if he can really do it.

On this project a lot of people have resigned over the last 2 years, and I almost did too, last year, but my final decision was to stay.

Last week my boss told me I'm going to get a consistent raise (this because a colleague of mine will leave the company), but I'm now thinking of leaving too.

I am getting paid well, but the work environment is not good for me anymore, and I'm feeling I'm hitting a plateau. If I accept the raise and stay, I'll do it only for the money.

Should I refuse the raise and tell him I want to leave, or accept it and then leave when I'll get an offer?

It seems unprofessional to me to accept it and then resign after 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> telling me that he now has to see **if he can really do it**.

So the details of the raise are not actually guaranteed...

> On this project a lot of people have resigned over the last 2 years, and I almost did too, last year, but my final decision was to stay.

If more people leave the same project in a short amount of time, there must be something company-related driving the people away. Do you want to be the hero, leaving the sinking ship the last, or you want a good job and a good health?

> but the work environment is not good for me anymore, and I'm feeling I'm hitting a plateau

Work environment is one of the most important details of a workplace, because it has a direct impact on your health (both physical and mental). Hitting a plateau is bad for your future professional life.

> Should I refuse the raise ...

No! why? You deserve it. Even thought the amount is related to the other people leaving, it is still your right.

> and tell him I want to leave ...

Definitely NOT! Never tell your employer about your plans to leave the company, before you have another guaranteed alternative.

> **... or accept it and then leave when I'll get an offer?**

**The best course of action :)**

Answer (score 4):

> *....or accept it and then leave when I'll get an offer?*

**This**.

You have no business telling someone, anyone in the organization that you're planning to leave. Follow the regular process till time you have another offer signed and sealed and then handover the notice and inform about your last day.

This is the most professional way to handle scenarios like you mentioned. Until you have a finalized and confirmed offer, you should never mention your intention of leaving - **plans and expectations can always go south, don't take a call today based on some probable future events, unless you know for sure.**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you signed the contract, do NOT inform the current company intent to leave. The raise is for your performance. So, it is perfectly OK to accept the raise.

There are be many things that can delay job search. You may change the mind, circumstances change and many other things. So, wait and continue as if you will be working there for foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

No,dont refuse the raise. As you said, you are getting the raise as it is due and not because he wants you to stay long.If it was the latter you would have had to think about it, but not if the raise is due for all employees!